# Color osmnx map by place (using graph_from_place() method)

Tags: python, openstreetmap, maps, append, osmnx

Let's say we want to graph the two below villages, which are in the UK. We also want to colour the streets by length. We can do:

```
# Get data
import osmnx as ox
place = ["Broughton Hackett", "Crowle"]
G = ox.graph_from_place(place, retain_all=True, simplify = True, network_type='all')

# Prepare data
u = []
v = []
key = []
data = []
for uu, vv, kkey, ddata in G.edges(keys=True, data=True): # added ww
    u.append(uu)
    v.append(vv)
    key.append(kkey)
    data.append(ddata)

# Define colors according to length of streets
roadCols = []

for item in data:    
    if "length" in item.keys():
        if item["length"] <= 200:
            color = "#FFFFF0"             
        elif item["length"] > 200 and item["length"] <= 1000:
            color = "#6a0dad"  
        else:
            color = "#00FFFF"
    else:
        color = "#FFFFFF"         
    roadCols.append(color)

#Plot 
bgcolor = "#1e1e1e"
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, node_size=0, 
                        dpi = 100,bgcolor = bgcolor,
                        save = False, edge_color=roadCols,
                        edge_linewidth=1, edge_alpha=1)
fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
fig.savefig("stack.jpg", dpi=100, bbox_inches='tight', format="jpg", 
            facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=False)
```

As we can see in output below, streets have been coloured according to their length.

[image: Illustration]

**My question**: how do we colour streets by place, not length? So that all streets of the first village are in one colour, and that all streets of the other village are in another colour?

Contrary to length, the place is not contained in the `data` object, and I don't know how to retrieve it from `G`.

I have tried to append the names to the object `data` manually, but I couldn't make it work. I have also tried to create two `G` objects (i.e., one for each village), but then it is not possible to graph them in a single command.

Note this is a mock example and that I have intentionally chosen tiny villages. In reality, I want to colour by several large cities or areas.

Comment: IMHO you may only get the following list of attributes from the `G` : `['osmid', 'lanes', 'ref', 'highway', 'maxspeed', 'oneway', 'length', 'geometry', 'name', 'service', 'bridge']`. So, I would either (1) join by location when node/edge is within the place's geometry with GeoPandas ? (2) geocode using the [`ox.geocoder.geocode_to_gdf(["W109318172"], by_osmid=True)`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.geocoder.geocode_to_gdf) that will have the attribute `"display_name"` (*A422, Broughton Hackett, Wychavon, ...*) and join by `"osmid"`, `ox.graph_to_gdfs()` may be needed

Comment: @Taras thanks! Will try.